# React - Migrating to React Router 4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am in the process of migrating my React App from React-Router-3 to React-Router-4 and I am having a few issues. The layout of my application is as follows.

```
build
node_modules
public
src
  AboutScreen
  ContactScreen
  HomeScreen
  LoginScreen
  SignUpScreen
  WorkRequestScreen
  App.js
  index.js
  routes.js
  serviceWorker.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

I am getting the following error:

> ./src/index.js: Line 8:  Unexpected use of 'history'  no-restricted-globals

When I remove the `history={history}` from `index.js`, I get the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

I have been following the following tutorial to migrate from 3 to 4.

> https://codeburst.io/react-router-v4-unofficial-migration-guide-5a370b8905a

My `route.js` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHashHistory from 'history/createHashHistory';
import App from './App';

import Home from './HomeScreen/Home';
import WorkReq from './WorkRequestScreen/WorkReq';
import About from './AboutScreen/About';
import Contact from './ContactScreen/Contact';
import Login from './LoginScreen/Login';
import Signup from './SignUpScreen/Signup';

const history = createHashHistory();
const routes = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/workReq" component={WorkReq}/>
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
      <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

export default routes;
```

My `index.js` looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { Route, Redirect, Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import routes from './routes'; 

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history} routes={routes}/>, 
document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing history explicitly isn't required as `Route` is passed `history` implicitly as prop. <sup>[1](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props)</sup>

I'd remove `history` prop passed to `Router` from the `index.js` and also remove it from `Router` in `routes.js`

Comment: After doing that, I get the error that I have mentioned in my questions edit. The error is: TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Comment: Where is this TypeError happening at? `index.js` doesn't reference `location` so one of the modules imported should have that property referenced. Also, what is `createHashHistory` doing?

Comment: The error is occuring at: /node_modules/react-router/es/Router.js:66. createHeashHistory from what I understand was creating the history object according to the article I was following. i have linked it above. After removing history though, it is not doing anything.

Comment: You can use `HashRouter` component from `react-router` https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter. I find this a better approach to injecting history